# Using bootstrap 3 Modal and JSF 2.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to open a Modal Bootstrap Dialog with a h:commandLink but without success. Let's see my code:

1 - I have this commandLink:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head />
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/templates/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form>
...

<h:commandLink>
                                                <f:passThroughAttribute name="data-toggle" value="modal" />
                                                <f:passThroughAttribute name="data-target"
                                                    value="#formBanca" />
                                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                            </h:commandLink>
...

            </h:form>
```

And after close tag "" i have the dialog DIV:

```
<!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="formBanca" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">...</div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save
                            changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When i click in commandLink the ManagedBean is called but dialog don't open. 
A very strange thing is that i tested in my Smartphone (Android) and dialog showed but with "loading bar in loop", let me try explain: is like page trying refresh but dialog stoped the refresh and "address bar" frozen in load.

Comment: Try it with an `<h:link/>` instead. `commandLink` is not recommended for client-side-only interactions

Comment: The solution was another: i added a "<f:ajax rendred=@all />"  and everything works fine.